# Syntax Highlighting isn't working correctly for c# 10.0 in vscode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

Starting from *c# 10.0* came a new way of a namespace declaration, aka [File-Scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#file-scoped-namespace-declaration). For [**Visual Studio 2022**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RI6ae.png) all look fine, but not for **VSCode**: See the [old way of namespace declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvYTT.png) and the [new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIRJk.png).
And it's not up to the selected theme.
Is it possible to get around this problem?

Comment: Which version? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136195

Comment: C# extension: 1.23.17, last updated: 12/3/2021; vscode: 1.63.0 (checked for updates, it doesn't need to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue recently. I think that OmniSharp is not up to date yet. To fix the issue, add these settings to the Settings JSON:

```
"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
"csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
```

That worked for me.

Comment: It's really worked...practically worked for me. The only ones that has remained the same (still colored in white) is type keywords. Anyway, it looks much better, finally!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me with VSCode 1.63 and C# extension version 1.23.17.

[image: Sample picture with working highlightning for file level namespaces.]

Make sure that both versions are up to date. It should auto update extensions and suggest updates for VSCode itself as default but it seems like it isn't updating properly for everyone (or at least not fast enough).

Comment: I have the same versions for both _vscode_: **1.63.0**  and _C# extension_ (last updated:
12/3/2021, 15:29:51): **v1.23.17**. All my extensions are synchronized.